# DAX - divide sum of each group by the total sum of all groups in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have below table as shown in the screenshot. I have a measure called Together which sums the APP and POS value for each city.
Now i need to divide the sum value of each city under the Together column over the sum of all cities under same column.

so for the first city i should have 272/3800 =  0.0715
second city, 271/3800 = 0.0713
.
.
.
And so on.

How do i calculate this using DAX?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QClPD.png)

What i tried is Divide(Together, Sum(Together)) but it gives 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Together measure

```
Together = SUMX('Cities',[App]+[Pos])
```

Step 2: AllCities measure

```
AllCities = CALCULATE([Together],ALL('Cities'[City]))
```

Step 3: Share measure

```
Share = DIVIDE([Together],[AllCities],BLANK())
```

Looks like you're coming from Excel, because the logic you outlined is normal Excel logic. If you think in terms of a database instead, then the logic may be easier. ALL() and REMOVEFILTERS() remove some or all parts of a filter context (In AllCities measure, I'm removing the [City] part of the filter context, so that I get the total for all cities. Then I Divide in Share. (Sure, I could do it in one measure, but I find it easier to understand if I do it a piece at a time).